# Changing "dot" to "dash" in "tcolorbox" package

Tags: tcolorbox

I have created a box by using `tcolorbox` package that has been shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to change “dot” to “dash”. How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the `number freestyle` option when defining the `tcolorbox` environment.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number freestyle=
                      \noexpand\thesubsection-\noexpand \arabic{\tcbcounter}]
             {example}{Example}{colbacktitle=green!50!black}{exp}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}} % for the dash in 
                                                               % the subsection number
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\section{second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{example}{}{example1}
This is an example
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: @Amin I am happy that your problem has been fixed. Nevertheless try next time to consider  **Dexteritas**'s comments by providing a minimal working example (MWE) in the question and by accepting one of the answers if that answer fit you best. (;-)